# Form submission shows up a blank entry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Code down here:

```
<?php require_once('verbinding.php') ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blog Arena 2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mooi.css">
</head>
<body>
      <!--- navigatie --->
      <?php include('./includes/navigatie.php') ?>
      <!--- header --->
      <?php include('./includes/header.php') ?>
        <h5> Registeer je nu ! Register now ! I cant choose English or Dutch ! </h5>
        <form action='registersubmit.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="test">
                  <label>Username</label> <input type='text' name='rusername' value=''><br>
              </div>
              <div class="test">
                  <label>E-mail</label> <input type='text' name='remail' value=''><br>
              </div>
                  <div class="test">
                    <label>Password</label> <input type='password' name='rpassword' value=''><br>
              </div>
              <div class="test">
                  <label>Confirm password</label>
                  <input type="password" name='rpassword_2'>
              </div>
              <div class="test">
                <input type='submit' name='save' class='knop'><br>
              </div>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And verbinding.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//verbinding met de database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "elly", "elly", "blog");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Er zijn problemen met het verbinden aan de database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//als ik het goed begrijp is Base Url  verwijzing voor verschillende OS-es
//define    ('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define  ('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/');

/* $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if($result ->num_rows > 0){
    echo "We have data";
} else {
    echo "we dont have data";
} */
?>
```

And the script that runs when submitting the form:

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$rusername = "";
$remail    = "";

var_dump($_POST);

// connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'elly', 'elly', 'blog');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $rusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rusername']);
    $remail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['remail']);
    $rpassword_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rpassword_1']);
    $rpassword_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rpassword_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
    // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
    if (empty($rusername)) { echo "Username is required"; }
    if (empty($remail)) { echo "Email is required"; }
    if (empty($rpassword_1)) { echo "Password is required"; }
    if ($rpassword_1 != $rpassword_2) {
        echo "The two passwords do not match";
    }

    // first check the database to make sure
    // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$rusername' OR email='$remail' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['username'] === $rusername) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $remail) {
            array_push($errors, "email already exists");
        }
    }

    // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $rpassword = md5($rpassword_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: user.php');
    }
}
```

I might have used to much spaces I am spending 20 minutes trying to post :P I am very new to programming. I hear in stackoverflow people burn you down, well I am ready. This is how I learn.

My problem is that if I add a user to the users table it will turn up blank in the database, there is an entry but no information filled in. Can anyone help me with this?

Just to be sure this is my table:

```
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('Author','Admin') DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

This is the table output (note I added Elmo myself via terminal:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| id | username | email               | role | password | created_at          | updated_at |
+----+----------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 | elmo     | elmo@sesamstraat.nl | NULL | elmo     | 2018-07-05 10:23:13 | NULL       |
|  2 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 14:47:04 | NULL       |
|  3 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 14:55:44 | NULL       |
|  4 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 15:27:38 | NULL       |
|  5 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 16:06:01 | NULL       |
|  6 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 16:07:55 | NULL       |
|  7 |          |                     | NULL |          | 2018-07-06 16:17:10 | NULL       |
+----+----------+---------------------+------+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Even escaping the strings is not 100% safe. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its all because you are inserting variables that do not even exist. Check the names of your variables. Also turn on error and notice reporting so you can spot these 'use of undefined' easier. Put this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to make sure it is more secure definitely.

Yes when I register it immediatly says you are now logged in $username    

This is the table output, is that okay if that past here ? 

But I will use your error report Incredible HAT and come back to here.

Comment: By the way, using `mysqli_real_escape_string` IS safe so long as you do not fall within the obscure edgecases with goofy database setups, and forget single quotes. It's just more obviously 'clean' if you use prepared statements so you don't have to second-guess or worry about the edge cases.

Comment: Also md5 is no use for hashing passwords (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), it's been insecure for years - too easy to crack it using brute force. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem is you're inserting the values from empty fields into your database:

```
"INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
```

However `$username`, `$email`, and `$password` are never declared in your code until that point. The variables you populated earlier are `$rusername`, `$remail` and `$rpassword`. You need to use these as the inputs to your query.

Comment: That would do it ;) @Codelly if the question doesn't get closed as a 'typo question', you should accept this answer so we know you have completed your request (welcome to stackoverflow!).

Comment: I am so new to this site :D, but so much answers so quick :D will check it right now. Learned a lot already ! But emberassed if I posted and it turns out to be a typo. Ill get back to you!

Comment: oh dangit its true !!!! I will double check 20 times before I post next time. Thanks for the help !!!!